# Many "Emulator unknown emulator - xxxx [null]"s are redundantly shown in android studio

Tags: android, hibernate, android-emulator

this is more of a benign bug in android studio. Whenever I wake my computer from sleep or hibernate the connection between the emulator and android studio is not proper and I have to restart the emulator and try again, so as a result of that (I think) all the dead emulators are always shown in the listing when trying to run the app.

And FYI I don't usually restart/shutdown my computer (once in 10 days or so). I was just wondering if there was a way to fix this bug without having to restart the computer.

[image: Dead Emulators]

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yzJl.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue using Windows 10 hibernate.

Try terminating the `adb.exe` process in the task manager. <strike>Sometimes you will find two or more `adb.exe` processes, kill them all. Then close all running emulators (if any) and disconnect all physical devices.</strike>

You don't have to restart android studio or eclipse.

After dong this, all unknown/null emulators should be gone (at least in my case).

Comment: Confirmed.  My Windows 7 PC never hibernates, but it does go to screensaver.  I notice this after a few days.  I only have 1 adb.exe, but killing it, and then trying to launch debug in AS works, as it just relaunches adb.

Comment: "adb kill-server" from the command line works more gracefully than killing the task.

Comment: @Kuff Thanks for the tip. It is indeed more graceful and efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Did you open multiple android studio and use the terminal in android studio?
you can close all android studio, and restart them. the unknown emulator will be gone

Comment: this is also what i do when that problem comes